# Scroll a website via Window.Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys i have been trying to scroll the website by adding a small piece of code to the inspect element.

The code

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}

<a href="javascript:pageScroll()">Scroll Page</a>
```

When i add this code on the inspect element the link appear on the webpage but it doesnt scroll down ..

Hope you guys can help me ..!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
   function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
    }
</script>
 <a href="javascript:pageScroll()">Scroll Page</a>
  <p>some really large content for scrolling ....</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

On the [website you got the code from](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html) it works properly.

Is something on your page goofy?

And if you're trying to scroll **on somebody else's page** with that (like entering it in the console), you'll have to call the `pageScroll()` function like this:

```
function pageScroll() {
//code
}
pageScroll();
```

and exclude the `<a href=...` nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this jQuery solution to animate a scroll. You need to add an element with an id to where you want to scroll to, and then call the function with that id

If you want you can also change the page URL and title with history.js

Html:

```
<a href="javascript:ScrollToHash('content');">Scroll to panel</a>

...

<div id="content" data-title="Page title here">
```

Script:

```
function ScrollToHash(hash) {

var id = hash.replace('#', '');

if ($('#' + id).length > 0) {

    var top = $('#' + id).offset().top;

    if (id == "home") { top = 0; }

    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: top
    }, 500, function () { // do something on complete function });

// Optional: Change page URL and title with history.js
    var ttl = $('#' + id).attr("data-title") + ' - Marbles';
    History.pushState(null, ttl, $('#' + id).attr("data-page-url"));
    $("title").text(ttl);

}
```

}